# Model data from a web API in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I know that it is possible to model objects, other than tables and views, in Entity Framework, such as stored procedures, but is it possible to model the results of a call to a Web API?

Eg. I have a database table called person that is modelled using entity framework. That person has an address and the id of that address is stored on the person record. When I return a person record using linq to entities I also want to return the address child record. The problem is that the address record can only be accessed through a call to a webapi - something like: /api/addresses/123.

My application needs to sort and search on fields in the address, so, as far as it is concerned, it must be queryable using linq to entities in the same way that every field in the person class is.

Any ideas out there?

Comment: XY problem. OP obviously does not know about OData/WCF Data Service or various projects to serialize `ExpressionTree`s. `EntityFramework` is only 1 of many Linq providers out there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know where there is a way to have a single linq statement whose results are combination of two linq providers? (The more I think about this, the more impossible it seems...)